# Can we take two temperature ranges for this probability?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> "Electronic sensors of a certain type fail when they become too hot.
>   The temperature at which a randomly chosen sensor fails is *T* ºC,
>   where *T* is modelled as a normal random variable with a mean of 94.5
>   and a standard deviation of 5.7.
>
> The manufacturers wish to quote a safe operating temperature at which
>   99% of the sensors will work. What temperature should they quote?"

---

Approach: Let's say **below** *c* ºC, 99% will be working, so 1% will fail; P(*T*≤*c*)=0.01 , *c*=81

---

My question is, can we (or is it logical to) find **above** what temperature the 99% of the sensors will function? i.e. P(*T*≥*a*)=0.01

Comment: That would give $c=107.76$, so the sensor could operate under 81 or above 108, but is the answer both? (The book says "81 ºC" only).

Comment: Actually sorry I misread the question. You want $\Pr(T \leq c) = .01$, or equivalently $P(T > c) = .99$.